# Converting MySQL query to json in PHP

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a code which runs a query and display it as a table on a page and right after convert the query to json variable. Unfortunately, the conversion to json variable does not get populated and when I print the json variable I only receive the column names without the data.

This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) {
    $_SESSION['variable'] = $_GET['variable'];
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select q1.variable, t3.label, q1.numvalue, description, num_cases from (select variable, numvalue, count(variable) as num_cases from nhws.num_all_{$_SESSION['country']} where variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}' group by variable, numvalue) q1 inner join (select * from nhws.luvalues where source = '{$_SESSION['country']}' and variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}') t2 on q1.numvalue=t2.numvalue inner join (select * from nhws.luvariables where source = '{$_SESSION['country']}' and variable = '{$_SESSION['variable']}') t3 on q1.variable=t3.variable;");
    echo "<h5>Counts</h5>";
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table><tr><th>Variable</th><th>label</th><th>Numvalue</th><th>Description</th><th>Num Cases</th></tr>";
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<tr><td>" . $row["variable"]. "</td><td>" . $row["label"]. "</td><td>" . $row["numvalue"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"]. "</td><td>" . $row["num_cases"]. "</td></tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";
    } else {echo "0 results";} 

    $rows = array();
    //flag is not needed
    $flag = true;
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'variable', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'num_cases', 'type' => 'number')

    );

    $rows = array();
    while($r = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
         $temp = array();
         // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
         $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r["variable"]); 

         // Values of each slice
         $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r["num_cases"]);
         $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
}
?>
```

As you can see the json variable only stores two columns out of the 5 columns that the query returns. the columns which the json variable need to store are "variable" and "num_cases".

Any suggestions why the json variable doesn't get populated using this code?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have to do a http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.data-seek.html to reset the pointer to the start of the returned result.

Comment: Also check if `echo json_last_error_msg();` prints anything interesting. Place it after the `json_encode` statement.

Comment: @jeff you are correct! I add this line `mysqli_data_seek($results, 0);` before the while loop and it worked. Feel free to write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array for JSON in the same loop you build your table rows, and then encode and deliver it later.

```
$dataForJson = [];  
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row["variable"]. "</td><td>" . $row["label"]. "</td><td>" . $row["numvalue"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"]. "</td><td>" . $row["num_cases"]. "</td></tr>";
      $dataForJson[] = $row;
}
echo "</table>";

echo json_encode($dataForJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop here loops through all your results, advancing the pointer each time: `while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {`, by the time it ends, the pointer is at the end of your results and when you try to loop again with `while($r = $results->fetch_assoc()) {` the pointer is still at the end of the results.

Before you start the second loop, reset the pointer to the first result using `mysqli_data_seek($results, 0)`